# Install Incrontab (file system watcher) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, cron, directory

Can someone please help me to install Incrond on my Ubuntu server, I tried all possible ways as I found on the web but nothing works.

```
sudo apt-get install incron

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package incrond
```

I need to install the file system watcher for some of my automization scripts to work.

Thank you in advance.

**Info: Yes the solution was the universe repository but in my case I wasn't aware which repository is responsible for incron, so it will be helpful to keep it separate.**

Comment: Next time visit https://packages.ubuntu.com first and you [will find](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=incron&searchon=names).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your apt source list file `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains `universe`.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
```

Install incron package.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install incron
```

Comment: pater,

its the same issue as before.

`sudo apt install incron
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package incron`

Comment: Sorry for the type in my question , I have already tired incron

Comment: It is part of universe repo list provided in Ubuntu by default. Can you check universe is there in apt source list file /etc/apt/sources.list  ?

Comment: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main`

Comment: this are the source list

Comment: you need to add universe repo: `sudo apt-add-repository universe`

Comment: @KetankumarPatel, thank you for the Help. it worked